# Unit testing Angular interceptor without Testbed using Jest. How to check headers were appended with bearer token. [Subscription returns nothing]

Tags: angular, rxjs, ts-jest, angular-http-interceptors, angular-unit-test

So I'm attempting to unit test my interceptor with out using testbed. The interceptor merely appends the Auth headers with a bearer token. I can't seem to figure out how to actually check that those headers have been appended. When subscribe to the interceptor returning the observable next.handle() I get nothing as a response, further to that all code in the subscribe block doesn't execute. I'm using Angular version 15.2.2 and Jest 28.1.3 and RxJs 7.5.6.

**Interceptor**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  return this.authService.acquireToken().pipe(
    switchMap((data: any) => {
      if (data !== null) {
        let updatedRequest: HttpRequest<any>;
        const authToken = data.accessToken;
        updatedRequest = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
          },
        });
        updatedRequest.headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
        return next.handle(updatedRequest);
      }
    })
  );
} else {
  return EMPTY;
}
```

**Unit test**

```
it('[Intercept] Should intercept the API requests and append auth token if user logged in', (done: DoneCallback) => {
const next: any = {
  handle: () => {
    return Observable.create((subscriber) => {
      subscriber.complete();
    });
  },
};
const requestMock = new HttpRequest('GET', '/test');
const y = interceptor.intercept(requestMock, next).pipe(
  map((r) => r),
  catchError(() => throwError('err')),
  take(1),
  finalize(() => {
    done();
  })
);
y.subscribe((i) => {
  console.log('API call intercepted'), console.log(requestMock.headers);
});
```

});

Any help would be appreciated because I'm totally lost! Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 updatedRequest.headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
```

This line won't modify `updatedRequest.headers`, [it will create new  HttpHeaders instance instead](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#append).

The code inside subscribe is not executed because the Observable never emits any value, it just completes immediately.

This is how I test similar interceptor in my application:

```
it('should add authorization header', () => {

    // interceptor depends on AuthStateService
    authStateService.setState({
      token: 'fake-token'
    })

    const next: HttpHandler = {
      handle: () => {
        return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<any>) => {
          subscriber.complete();
        });
      }
    };
    const requestMock = new HttpRequest('GET', '/test');

    spyOn(next, 'handle').and.callThrough();

    tokenInterceptor.intercept(requestMock, next).subscribe();

    expect(next.handle).toHaveBeenCalledWith(requestMock.clone({
      headers: requestMock.headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer fake-token`)
    }))

  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that @displayName. That's exactly the answer, working like a charm now. Not included in the question was:

    mockAuthenticationService = {
      isLoggedIn: () => true,
      acquireToken: () => of({ accessToken: 'lewis' }),
    };

So not really sure, attempting to log a response in your code also didn't work. 
And thank you for pointing out my mistake with the headers, it makes learning a lot more enjoyable! Will mark this as the resolution, cheers.

Comment: @LewisMorgans I think code inside subscribe doesn't get executed because the Observable never emits any value. It just completes immediately. If you add `subscriber.next(someValue)` before `subscriber.complete()` it should get executed. However, it's not really important for the test if you write it this way.